# How to use $compile inside an AngularJS link function with a $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Using AngularJS and Angular-UI Tooltip (uib-tooltip) to setup a tooltip system that allows the user to turn the tooltips on & off.  I'd also like to keep the text in a central location for easy editing.  I'm running into trouble, however, replicating the tooltip-enable portion of the uib-tooltip directive which toggles the on/off portion.

The standard approach.

```
<ul id="realmContainer" uib-tooltip="Even more stuffs" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-enable="userService.data.current.preferences.activeTooltips">

...
```

My HTML

```
<ul id="realmContainer" tip>
```

The "tip" directive

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.directives')
        .directive('tip', ['$rootScope', 'userService', '$compile', Tooltip]);

    /* @ngInject */
    function Tooltip($rootScope, userService, $compile) {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 10000,
            terminal: true,
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            // lookup and assign the tooltip by ID
            attrs.$set('uib-tooltip', dictionary[element[0].id]);
            attrs.$set('tooltip-placement', attrs['tip-position'] || 'bottom');
            // Remove the 'tip' attribute so we don't get stuck in a loop
            attrs.$set('tip', null);
            // compile the new HTML.  This works so far
            $compile(element)(scope);

             //I just can't get this to recompile the html when the value changes
            scope.userService = userService;
            scope.$watch('userService.data.current.preferences.activeTooltips', function(newValue, oldValue){
                var isVisible = newValue === undefined ? true : newValue;
                // This sets true/false in the DOM
                attrs.$set('tooltip-enable', isVisible);
                // Mouseover event still triggers even after removing
                // tooltip-enable.  What gives?
                $compile(element)(scope);
            })
        }
    }

    var dictionary = {
        realmContainer: 'Even more stuffs'
    }
})();
```

It seems like the tooltip always displays on mouseover.  The $watch picks up the new value, but the $compile doesn't seem to remove the mouseover trigger from the DOM.

Any help would be appreciated.